# Why is this "Loop Body" is empty?

Tags: c++

I took a test and got this answer wrong and am not sure why. Can someone help me?

```
**In the following segment of code, 
number = 1 
while(number <= 10); 
{
cout<<number<<endl; 
}
```

the body of the loop is *_*_.**

```
           **A. empty
```

Incorrect   B. everything in between the curly brackets
               C. cout<
               D. number <= 10;**

Answer Key: A

Comment: while(number <= 10); <-- that thing

Comment: @thang is pointing to the semicolon.

Comment: Please reformat/indent your question

Answer (score 5):

The semicolon immediately after terminates the `while` block.

Answer (score 2):

The while loop will apply to the next statement or statement block following the expression `while(number <= 10)`

In this case you have a semi-colon `;` following it, this is known as the empty statement and is a valid statement. It is the only statement that will execute in this while loop.

The block defined in curly braces after the empty statement is independent of the while loop. You can place blocks of code in curly braces without having to attach them to a function definition or a loop, for instance.